# Calculating frequencies in R

Tags: r, frequency

My dataset looks like this:

```
genera
             Genus Location Number
    1                             NA
    2    Terriglobus       CC      1
    3    Terriglobus        N      5
    4 Acidobacterium       CC      2
    5 Acidobacterium        N     12
    6   Edaphobacter       CC      0
```

I want to do do two things 1) delete rows with any NA in any column and 2) calculate the frequencies for each genus in both location, CC and N.

I have been trying to use

```
AB<-genera[genera[, "Location"] == "CC", ] #to keep all separate the rows by location 
CD<-genera[genera[, "Location"] == "N", ]
```

I want to use table or `prop.table` and calculate the frequencies each, but I am having difficulties because I just get `NA NA NA  NA  NA NA  NA`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at `?na.omit` for (1), and `?aggregate` for (2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, using @RichardScriven's `dat`:

```
with(na.omit(dat), aggregate(Number, list(Genus=Genus, Location=Location), sum))

#            Genus Location  x
# 1 Acidobacterium       CC  2
# 2   Edaphobacter       CC  0
# 3    Terriglobus       CC  1
# 4 Acidobacterium        N 12
# 5    Terriglobus        N  5
```

---

**Edit**

Given the clarification in your comments on other solutions, I now suggest the following, which calculates, for each `Genus` and `Location`, the `Number` as a proportion of the sum of `Number` at the location. Again, starting with @RichardScriven's `dat`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(dat$Location), function(x) {
  d <- subset(dat, Location==x)
  cbind(Location=x, aggregate(d$Number, list(Genus=d$Genus), 
                              function(x) sum(x)/sum(d$Number)))
}))

#   Location          Genus         x
# 1       CC Acidobacterium 0.6666667
# 2       CC   Edaphobacter 0.0000000
# 3       CC    Terriglobus 0.3333333
# 4        N Acidobacterium 0.7058824
# 5        N    Terriglobus 0.2941176
```

However, if each `Genus` only occurs once per `Location`, you can simplify to:

```
lapply(split(dat, list(dat$Location), drop=TRUE), function(x) 
  transform(x, propn=x$Number/sum(x$Number)))

# $CC
#            Genus Location Number     propn
# 2    Terriglobus       CC      1 0.3333333
# 4 Acidobacterium       CC      2 0.6666667
# 6   Edaphobacter       CC      0 0.0000000
# 
# $N
#            Genus Location Number     propn
# 3    Terriglobus        N      5 0.2941176
# 5 Acidobacterium        N     12 0.7058824
```

This could then be combined into a single data frame with `do.call(rbind, x)`, where `x` is the list created above.

Finally, you could use `dplyr` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %.%
  group_by(Location) %.%
  mutate(total = sum(Number), Propn = Number/total) %.%
  select(-total)

#            Genus Location Number     Propn
# 1    Terriglobus       CC      1 0.3333333
# 2    Terriglobus        N      5 0.2941176
# 3 Acidobacterium       CC      2 0.6666667
# 4 Acidobacterium        N     12 0.7058824
# 5   Edaphobacter       CC      0 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 3):

`prop.table` needs a table object to start with:

```
 prop.table( table(genera$CC) )
```

If "Number" is a count then you would probably want `tapply` with sum of `Number`. Perhaps something along these lines:

```
prop.table( with(genera, tapply(Number, CC, sum) ) )
```

`xtabs` will also do sums:

```
 prop.table( xtabs( Number ~ CC, data=genera) )
```

Comment: What if both location have different lengths of genera?

Answer (score 3):

I had to add two NULL values to make the table.

```
> dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'Genus Location Number
  1           NULL     NULL     NA
  2    Terriglobus       CC      1
  3    Terriglobus        N      5
  4 Acidobacterium       CC      2
  5 Acidobacterium        N     12
  6   Edaphobacter       CC      0', row.names = 1)
```

With regard to your first question, you can remove the rows with NA numbers with `which` and `is.na`

```
> newDat <- dat[-which(is.na(dat$Number)), ]
> newDat
           Genus Location Number
2    Terriglobus       CC      1
3    Terriglobus        N      5
4 Acidobacterium       CC      2
5 Acidobacterium        N     12
6   Edaphobacter       CC      0
```

For your second question, I think you may have frequency and percentage (or probability) confused. Frequency can be found by

```
> sapply(split(newDat, as.character(newDat$Genus)), function(x){
    sum(x$Number)
    })
Acidobacterium   Edaphobacter    Terriglobus 
            14              0              6
```

The percentage is a little different,

```
> pct <- with(newDat, Number/sum(Number))
> names(pct) <- newDat$Location
```

This will tell you, in order, the weight as a percentage that each location carries relative to the overall total.

```
> pct
  CC    N   CC    N   CC 
0.05 0.25 0.10 0.60 0.00
```

---

**ADDED**

On second thought, you may just need

```
> split(newDat[,c("Location", "Number")], newDat$Genus)
$Acidobacterium
  Location Number
4       CC      2
5        N     12

$Edaphobacter
  Location Number
6       CC      0

$Terriglobus
  Location Number
2       CC      1
3        N      5
```

Comment: Thank You I was able to delete all the NA rows. Now regarding the second part the code you suggested eliminates the location designation, which is needed to figure out the frequencies for each genus in each location.

Comment: For the 1st question, `dat[complete.cases(dat),]` - will take care of NA in *any* column.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I understand the frequency you want.  I thought you meant just the sum of both, by Genus.

Comment: Thank You :)The frequencies I would like to do is based on location so for Terriglobus the frequency for CC is 1/ sum(all counts in Numbers column in the CC location)

Comment: Thanks @Arun.  Didn't know about `complete.cases`

Comment: @user3018479, you have frequency confused with percentage (or probability).  Frequency is simple the number of times an event occurred, while the `1/sum(...)` in your comment is a percentage.

Comment: @RichardScriven in fact anything expressed as a fraction of the whole is a proportion, not a percentage (which is the rate in 100). But now we're nitpicking. ;)

Comment: Well, whatever.  It ain't the frequency.